# Meteor email not working - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: meteor

My meteor is currently running on my localhost.

I added the meteor email package

`meteor add email`

In `server/server.js` I added (my password has a ton of special characters (@#$%^&), if that makes any difference):

```
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://myusername%40gmail.com:mypassword@smtp.gmail.com:465/";
```

and then in the same file I added:

```
Email.send({
  from: "meteor.email.2014@gmail.com",
  to: "myusername@gmail.com",
  subject: "Meteor Can Send Emails via Gmail",
  text: "Its pretty easy to send emails via gmail."
});
```

Nothing gets sent. I get this in my Meteor console:

```
W20140607-11:37:24.449(8)? (STDERR) 
W20140607-11:37:24.452(8)? (STDERR) /home/wdi2p2/.meteor/tools/6f23056589/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
W20140607-11:37:24.453(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20140607-11:37:24.459(8)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20140607-11:37:24.466(8)? (STDERR) Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
W20140607-11:37:24.468(8)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (/home/wdi2p2/.meteor/tools/6f23056589/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
W20140607-11:37:24.469(8)? (STDERR)     at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:94)
W20140607-11:37:24.469(8)? (STDERR)     at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:155)
W20140607-11:37:24.470(8)? (STDERR)     at app/server/server.js:3:7
W20140607-11:37:24.471(8)? (STDERR)     at app/server/server.js:10:3
W20140607-11:37:24.474(8)? (STDERR)     at /home/wdi2p2/Workspace/WDI/VLP/home-photo-pros/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140607-11:37:24.474(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140607-11:37:24.475(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/wdi2p2/.meteor/tools/6f23056589/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140607-11:37:24.475(8)? (STDERR)     at /home/wdi2p2/Workspace/WDI/VLP/home-photo-pros/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
W20140607-11:37:24.476(8)? (STDERR)     - - - - -
W20140607-11:37:24.477(8)? (STDERR)     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
W20140607-11:37:24.477(8)? (STDERR)     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

This is the code that is responsible for ENOTFOUND

```
    it('times out on invalid host', function (done) {

        Sntp.time({ host: 'error', timeout: 10000 }, function (err, time) {

            expect(err).to.exist;
            expect(time).to.not.exist;
            expect(err.message).to.equal('getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND');
            done();
        });
    });
```

So I guess that the host is timing out for some reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` is usually a DNS error (address not found)

It may be your password that is confusing what the domain may be.

Do you have an `@` by any chance in your password? Try URL encoding it (password only).

Comment: I most definitely have an @ in the password. How do I URL encode my password? Never done it before.

Comment: Wait, I just realized that after I URL encode, the password would then need to be URL decoded back into the real password.... uhhh... how will all this work in the `MAIL_URL` environmental variable?

Comment: I think Meteor automatically does that for you. Try doing this `process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://myusername%40gmail.com:' + encodeURIComponent(<your password here>) + "@smtp.gmail.com:465"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! This was the actual code (your code had some small typos, just quotation stuff) `process.env.MAIL_URL='smtp://gmailusername%40gmail.com:' + encodeURIComponent("passwordInQuotes") + '@smtp.gmail.com:465';`

Comment: Hrmmm... are there limitations to `encodeURIComponent`? I tried this same code with another email account, one where the password contains @, $, %, !, and #. I get `W20140608-11:04:49.219(8)? (STDERR) URIError: URI malformed
W20140608-11:04:49.231(8)? (STDERR)     at decodeURIComponent (native)
`

Comment: I tried using fixedEncodeURIComponent from here and it still doesn't work - get the same error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny try changing your password so you use something else instead of @

Comment: Changing my password worked. But damn, there has got to be a better way?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny the official way is using the encodeuricomponent method, the same decoder, `decodeURIComponent` is used to decode it so its supposed to work. You could figure out where its going wrong by trying to run these lines of code with your password and see where its crashing & why: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/email/email.js#L9-L20

Comment: For using on Galaxy, I also tried putting the URL in settings.json. But got ENOTFOUND, the username was interpreted as server name. When using process.env.MAIL_URL (along with encodeURIComponent for the password) it worked.

Comment: Ty Very much my friend, this still work for me in nodemailer